# Animating a div in CSS in a clean loop

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is animated to smoothly move across the screen. This div contains the "latest news" from my site and its width depends on the title, so I can't set it beforehand. My problem is that when the titles are too long the animation takes too much time to start up and to loop after the end. Is there a way to make my animation loop as soon as the first one finishes? Here's the code I have now:

**HTML**

```
<div class="marquee">
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="moduleItemTitle">Test Text 1 Test Text 1 Test Text 1 Test Text 1 Test Text 1</a>
        <span style="float: left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <a href="#" class="moduleItemTitle">Test Text 2 Test Text 2 Test Text 2 Test Text 2 Test Text 2</a>
        <span style="float: left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <a href="#" class="moduleItemTitle">Test Text 3 Test Text 3 Test Text 3 Test Text 3 Test Text 3</a>
        <span style="float: left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <a href="#" class="moduleItemTitle">Test Text 4 Test Text 4 Test Text 4 Test Text 4 Test Text 4</a>
        <span style="float: left;">&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.marquee {
 height: 50px;   
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #000;
}

.marquee div {
 font-family: Verdana;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:24px;
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;

 width: -webkit-max-content;
 width: -moz-max-content;
 width: max-content;
 -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);       
 transform:translateX(100%);

 -moz-animation: example1 40s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: example1 40s linear infinite;
 animation: example1 40s linear infinite;
}

.marquee div a{
float: left;
color: #fff;
}

.marquee div span:last-child{
display: none;
}

@keyframes example1 {
 0%   {
 -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(100%);                 
 }

 100% {
 -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
 transform: translateX(-100%);
 }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ot5mmas/2/)

Comment: Google it ? http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-animation-advanced-marquee/

Comment: Google it you will find  this link. http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/XxUXD/